Programmatically create a Python function that takes exactly one more argument than a given function
Say I have a python function:
def my_func(first, second=2):
    return first * second

What I want is a way to generate a new function that takes exactly one more argument than my function and behaves like this:
def my_new_func(first, second=2, exclamation='hello'):
    print(exclamation)
    return my_func(first, second)

What's the best way to do this programmatically?  In my use case, it is very important that the signature of the programmatically generated version of my_new_func is exactly the same as what it looks like above.
So I don't think this would work:
def add_exclamation_to_func(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs, exclamation='hello'):
        print(exclamation)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    inner.__name__ = func.__name__
    inner.__doc__ = func.__doc__

    return inner

my_new_func = add_exclamation_to_func(my_func)

because in this case I think the signature of my_new_func will be a generic *args, **kwargs kind of thing.
Is there an easy way to do what I have in mind?

your code is fine, I'd reccomend using @wraps

As written, what will the signature of my_new_func be?  Is it (*args, **kwargs) or (first, second=2, exclamation='hello').  I would like it to be the latter.  I fear it is the former.

I'm not quite following, you want to keep the method signature but add a parameter to the signature?
The only thing i can come up with is the code below.
Is there any way this is an option?
import functools

def add_exclamation_to_func(exclaimation="hello"):
    def wrapper(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            print(exclaimation)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return wrapper

@add_exclamation_to_func()
def foo(var):
    print(var)

def bar(var):
    print(var)

def directly_called(var):
    print(var)

intermediate = add_exclamation_to_func("hello")(bar)

#yes i could have used foo for all of but w/e
foo("parameter to foo")
#>>> hello
#>>> parameter to foo
bar("parameter to bar without hello")
#>>> parameter to bar without hello
intermediate("parameter to bar with hello")
#>>> hello
#>>> parameter to bar without hello

add_exclamation_to_func("hello")(directly_called)("directly called")
#>>> hello
#>>> directly called

response to comment: you should be fine with functools.wraps
import functools
from inspect import signature

def decorated(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner(*args,exclamation="hello",**kwargs):
        print(exclamation)
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return inner

@decorated
def wrapped(var1, var2):
    print(var1)
    print(var2)

print(signature(wrapped))
#>>> (var1, var2)
wrapped(1,2,exclamation="message")
#>>> message
#>>> 1
#>>> 2


Say I have a function that takes two arguments (with names and default arguments), and I want to produce a function that takes three arguments (where the first two don't change, and the third gets printed).  How do I do that?  In the examples you wrote, if you typed foo(<SHIFT-TAB> in an interactive prompt, what would it show you was the signature of foo?

@8one6 updated the answer, you're fine if using functools.wraps

Approach statement
my_new_func should take the arguments from my_func dynamically, while being able to append new arguments to my_new_func
Code
import inspect

def my_func(first:int, second:int=2) -> int:
    return first * second

def my_new_func(func, exclamation:str='hello',IsCallToOriginal:bool=True, *args, **kwargs):
    #We'll get the arguments as stated by the calling function
    func_args = inspect.signature(func).parameters.keys()
    #By creating a dictionary we'll parse them back to the original function
    func_kwargs = {arg: kwargs[arg] for arg in func_args if arg in kwargs}
    #I'm assuming we have to call to the original by default?
    if IsCallToOriginal==True:
        result = func(**func_kwargs)

    print(exclamation)
    if IsCallToOriginal==True:
        return result
result = my_new_func(my_func, exclamation='hi', first=3, second=4)
print(result)  # Output: hi /n 12

